# Using rawpy to convert multiple raw .NEF Images to TIFF

Tags: python, image, image-processing, tiff, data-conversion

I have been searching through this forum but cannot find a relevant answer to my problem. I have only found solutions for single file conversions.

I want to convert a ***directory*** of Nikon RAW images (.NEF) into TIFF (.tiff). 
This can be achieved with the [rawpy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rawpy) plugin apparently. I am not well versed in python and have done my best. You will probably find my script laughable :)

I'd like to ideally be able to paste the directory path into the command line and have it convert everything for me, into 16-bit tiffs.

```
import rawpy
import imageio

paths = 'C:\Users\Jake\Desktop\Exposuretests\Darks'

for i in paths:
    with rawpy.imread(paths) as raw:
        rgb = raw.postprocess()
imageio.imsave(paths + '.tiff', rgb)
```

Thanks all in advance for any help. I am sure this is quite simple for those versed in python!

Answer (score 3):

You can do it very simply without having to write any Python or loops if you use **ImageMagick** which is installed on most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows.

In Terminal, simply type:

```
magick mogrify -format tif *NEF
```

Comment: In your Linux system, this could also be `mogrify -format tif *NEF` without having to include `magick`. Thanks @Mark!

Comment: @SébastienLavoie Actually, it depends on the version. With v7 of ImageMagick, you should use `magick mogrify ...`. If v6, omit the `magick`

Comment: That is indeed the reason why. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you already fixed this, but there are a few typos:

```
import rawpy
import imageio

paths = 'C:\Users\Jake\Desktop\Exposuretests\Darks'

for i in paths:
    with rawpy.imread(paths) as raw:
        rgb = raw.postprocess()
    imageio.imsave(paths + '\file_' + i + '.tiff', rgb)
```

Might do the trick.

Steve