# How to convert a NEF (raw image file type) to JPG in Python on Mac?

Tags: python, image, macos, image-processing

I am trying to convert a NEF RAW image to JPG, though what I found does not give me the exact rib values. 
The code I used is from this link: [Using rawpy to convert multiple raw .NEF Images to TIFF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42464319/using-rawpy-to-convert-multiple-raw-nef-images-to-tiff)

`for i in path:
    with rawpy.imread(path) as raw:
       rgb = raw.postprocess()
       print(rgb)
 imageio.imsave(path + '.jpg', rgb)`

From this code, it looks like I'm lacking the blue values (and yes, I have altered the path to make it Mac compatible).

Thank you

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm having the same problem. The output PNG has a big red shift for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem until I used the following:

```
rgb = raw.postprocess(rawpy.Params(use_camera_wb=True))
imshow(rgb)
plt.show()
```

Left shows after and right before with just raw.postprocess()
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in path:
   with rawpy.imread(path) as raw:
      rgb = raw.postprocess()
      print(rgb)
      imagename = str(path)+str(i)+".jpg"
      imageio.imsave(imagename, rgb)
```

can you try this?

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob
# All files and directories ending with .txt and that don't begin with a dot:
a=(glob.glob("D:\\ND750-1\\*.NEF")) 
import rawpy
import imageio
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm


for i in tqdm(a):
    with rawpy.imread(i) as raw:
        rgb = raw.postprocess()
    imageio.imsave(i.replace('NEF','jpg'), rgb)
```